# Why do we use double pointers to reference a 2D array allocated on the heap?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

So the lecture example has the following code

```
 int **a;
 a = new int*[10];
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
      a[i] = new int[5];
      for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j){
           a[i][j] = i*10+5;
      }
 }
```

And I have a few questions about the above code (and multidimensional arrays on the heap in general):

1. Do we ***have*** to initialize every element in the array as shown? Or is it suffice to cut the code after the a[i] = new int [5]?
2. I know with arrays allocated on the stack, it is illegal to use a variable as the stack size as

   cin >> n;

   int a[n];

   but is it legal for heap-allocated arrays? As in, a = new int[n]?
3. Why is it a double pointer pointing to this array? Usually for 1D arrays, we used a single pointer as int *a = new int[10]? If I wanted the value of the array element itself, do I deference twice as **a? Or do I still do *a?
4. So say I have a 2D array of objects of some Class. How would I access the member field var of the ith, jth element? What if I want to invoke the member function of the object in the ith, jth element?

Comment: Note that in "modern" C++ (21st century) we wouldn't do this anymore. We'd just write `std::vector<std::vector<int>> a(5, std::vector<int>(10));` to get a 5x10 zero-initialized 2D array. Your lecture is outdated by almost 2 decades.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You don't *have* to initialize every element in the array.  If you don't, the contents of the array will be undefined.  Alternatively, you can zero-initialize with `new int[5]()`.
2. `a = new int[n]` works on the heap because there's actually a run-time call to mark new memory for use as the data `a` is pointing to.  It can't work on the stack because the compiler needs to know how big the stack frame is for any particular function call, so the value must be computable at compile time.
3. You need a double pointer because a is a pointer to a *pointer to* an integer.  It points to an array of arrays, each of which needs to be dereferenced when accessing the value.  You would typically use a[i][j] to access a specific element, which effectively double-deferences.

Comment: `**a` gives you the first element of the first row.  One would normally use `a[i][j]` to access an element.  Also, a mention of `new int[5]()` to initialize to zeros would be good to mention in the answer.

Comment: @MooingDuck, I've incorporated the changes you suggested.

Comment: So I would use a[i][j] to access the int located in those indices. But if I have a 2D array of objects, how do I access the member variable of the object in the ith, jth element? What about if I want to invoke a member function of the object in the ith, jth element?

Answer (score 1):

If the number of columns in the matrix is known at compile time, you can just allocate a matrix:

```
int nrow = 10;                        // number of rows assigned at run time
int (*a)[5];                          // pointer to array of 5 ints
    a = new int[nrow][5];             // allocate matrix
    for (int i = 0; i < nrow; ++i)    // initialize matrix
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
            a[i][j] = i*nrow+j;
    // ...
    delete[] a;
```